# nested quadrature in matlab using two quadrature rules

Tags: matlab, math, integral

Stuck on numerically evaluating this integral and only have experience in doing simple quadrature schemes so bear with me if this looks amateurish. The nested integral is below using Gauss-Hermite(-inf,+inf) and a variant of Gauss Laguerre scheme (0,+inf) - over a gaussian and gamma(v/2,2) densities. I get to the point where the I m nearly finished the integration, intermediate steps look good, but I m stuck on how to combine the weights to evaluate the overall integral. I'd be really grateful for suggestions in modifing the code/other idea to code a better quadrature scheme that solves the problem. 
\begin{equation}
\int^{\infty}*{-\infty}\int^{\infty}*{0} \prod_{i=1}^n\Phi \left(\frac{\sqrt{w/v}\,C{i}-a{i}Z}{\sqrt{1a   {i^2}}\right)f{z}(Z)f{w}(W)dwdz
\end{equation}

% script defines nodes, weights, parameters then calls one main and one subfunction

rho=0.3; nfirms=10; h=repmat(0.1,[1,nfirms]); T=1; R=0.4; v=8; alpha=v/2;GaussPts=15;

```
% Quadrature nodes - gaussian and gamma(v/2) from Miranda and Fackler CompEcon
    % toolbox
[x_norm,w_norm] = qnwnorm(GaussPts,0,1);
[x_gamma,w_gamma] = qnwgamma(GaussPts,alpha);
L_mat=zeros(nfirms+1,GaussPts);

for i=1:1:GaussPts;
     L_mat(:,i) = TC_gamma(x_norm(i,:),x_gamma(i,:),h,rho,T,v,nfirms);
end; 

w_norm_mat= repmat(w_norm',nfirms+1,1);
w_gamma_mat = repmat(w_gamma',nfirms+1,1);
% need to weight L_mat by the gaussian and chi-sq i.e, (gamma v/2,2)?
ucl = L_mat.*w_norm;%?? HERE
ucl2 = sum(ucl.*w_gamma2,2);% ?? HERE


function [out] = TC_gamma(x_norm,x_gamma,h,rho,T,v,nfirms)
% calls subfunction feeds into recursion

qki= Vec_CondPTC_gamma(x_norm,x_gamma,h,rho,T,v)' ;

fpdf=zeros(nfirms+1,nfirms+1);
% start at the first point on the tree
 fpdf(1,1)=1; 
    for i=2:nfirms+1 ;
     fpdf(1,i)=fpdf(1,i-1)*(1-qki(:,i-1));
       for j=2:nfirms+1;
       fpdf(j,i)=fpdf(j,i-1)*(1-qki(:,i-1))+fpdf(j-1,i-1)*qki(:,i-1);
     end
   fpdf(i,i)=fpdf(i-1,i-1)*qki(:,i-1);
  end
out=fpdf(:,end);
end% of function TC_gamma


function qki= Vec_CondPTC_gamma(x_norm,x_gamma,h,rho,T,v) 
PD = (1-exp(-kron(h,T)));DB = tinv(PD,v);

a=rho.^0.5; sqrt1_a2 = sqrt(1-sum(a.*a,2));

aM = gtimes(a, x_norm'); Sqrt_W=gamcdf(x_gamma,v/2,2).^0.5;

DB_times_W= gtimes(DB,Sqrt_W); DB_minus_aM = gminus(DB_times_W',aM);

qki=normcdf(grdivide(DB_minus_aM,sqrt1_a2));
end% of function Vec_CondPTC
```

Comment: Your code is hard to read; can you please indent it? Also, why can you not just use the `quad` function in matlab?

Comment: Hi Issac,apologies indents added to improve readability; Three reasons 1. I ve not seen/used the inbuilt functions for integration of two differing densities (N(0,1) & Chi-sq here), 2 quad cant easily handle infinite limits like this case; 3 dblquad - needs areas to be mapped to a rectangle, not sure how to do this here. Open to suggestions.

Comment: The approach seems sound mathematically, I don't know enough matlab to help, but you'll have 2 nested loops, and you just have to multiply the weights.

Comment: Hi Alexandre, could you indicate how you would do this in C or someother language? It may be an issue with my scaling of the weights but simple element by element multiplication doesnt give the required results.

Comment: LaTeX markup seems broken; I tried to render it over on [math.se] (to insert screenshot here), but could not figure out what you mean by `\sqrt{1a {i^2}`

Comment: Not sure whats happening with Latex markup. In the code ai=rho.^0.5 and ai2=(1-ai.*ai).^0.5. Its the square root of the correlation to the common factor eqns 5 and 6 in this [link](https://www.business.unsw.edu.au/About-Site/Schools-Site/risk-actuarial-site/Documents/Y.%20Goegebeur,%20T.%20Hoedemakers%20and%20J.%20Tistaert%20-%20Synthetic%20CDO%20Pricing%20using%20the%20Student%20t%20Factor%20Model%20with%20Random%20Recovery.pdf)